# Android app start up animation

Tags: android, animation, startup

i just need to know how is it possible to create a start-up animation in your app. When the app is launched I would like it to go through custom animation and then it reaches the content of the app (main activity) ...

Thanks for all your help

Comment: It is possible, but kittens and unicorns die every time and Android app has a SplashScreen...

Comment: That's not entirely true, the kittens and unicorns die only if you set a timer to purposely show the splashscreen longer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want a "startup" screen, just load up another activity before the MainActivity and display that screen for x amount of time:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int TIME_OUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```